# How do I NOT create a "Brower Console" when I open a clean Firefox window?

Tags: boot

Possibly when 2020.04 is ready in a few months, *that* will fix this
problem.  Here are the details.

Whenever I launch my Firefox browser, within seconds a window labeled
"Browser Console" pops up.  I'd like to know how to do away with this
unnecessary window without having to click on the read "X" in the upper
right corner of the smaller "Browser Console" window.

In Other Words, What's the magic!?

Comment: Why is this tagged 'boot' and 'live-usb'? Are you doing this in a Live environment? When I tested Firefox last week in a 20.04 Live environment, I didn't get a Browser Console window...nor did I get one last month in an 18.04 Live environment.

Comment: I've been testing 20.04 in a VM over the past few weeks. I don't see any "Browser Console" window. I've never seen an unwanted Firefox "Browser Console" window in 18.04 either.